# AWS: how to create a private subnet to the default VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am following the [Hosting a Web App on Amazon Web Services](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/web-app-hosting-intro.html) tutorial.

It says that the EC2 instance should be launched into a public subnet. However, database Server should be launched into a private subnet. But when I try to create the private subnet, I have problem choosing CIDR. My default VPC is 172.31.0.0/16. If the CIDR is 172.31.x.0/16, it showed error that CIDR already existed.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Now I want to host a Tweet Trend application(similar to https://github.com/Leogogo1023/TweetMap)  to practice using  AWS. Because I am new to AWS, now I know how to launch EC2 instance into a public subnet. But I do not know how to host such application using elastic beanstalk correctly. Do I need to install anything on the EC2? How could I do this? Thanks.

Comment: @manetsus Thanks for your reply. Now I want host a java web application using AWS. This application use RDS for mySQL database. Now I want to know how to correctly set up RDS for the EC2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of the tutorial, feel free to create your database in a Public Subnet.

It is recommended best practice to launch private resources (which do not need to be accessed from the Internet) into a Private Subnet. However, rather than having to learn VPC at this stage in your learning process, feel free to create the database in the Public Subnet.

Later, when you have learned about VPCs, you can create your own VPC with public and private subnets for improved security.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for your reply. Because I launch the EC2 into a default public subnet. Do I need to launch the database in the same public subnet?

Comment: No. All subnets within a VPC can talk to each other. For the purpose of the tutorial, creating it in the same subnet makes sense since it is slightly better performance and you do not require High Availability.

Comment: Hi John, I still have a problem when using Eclipse AWS tookit. I want to deploy this sample application [Sample github](https://github.com/awslabs/eb-tomcat-snakes). The first step is to build the project. This sample uses git bash to build the project. Can I use eclipse to build the application?  I hope to use Eclipse Mars for Java EE developer to compile this sample web project into class files. After I right clicked the project and select build project, there is no error in the eclipse markers however I cannot find the class files in the build folder.

Comment: Could you tell me how to build the AWS web application using Eclipse? Thanks.

Comment: Please submit a new Question if you wish to ask something different to the original question.